# Unable to compare strings

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to compare two strings contry and answer.
myTextField is a textfield control and -country is NSArray
but it will always execute else block even when the two strings are equal

```
    NSString *answer = _myTextField.text;
    NSString *contry = _country[self.displayedFlagIndex];

    if ( [contry isEqualToString: answer])
    {
         NSString *test =@"if block ";

        NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@ is %@", test,answer, @"Correct!!"];
        _myTextField.text= result;
    }
```

Comment: are you sure they are both strings and equal to each other? can you set the breakpoint right before the if statement, and 'po' both of them in the console?

Comment: NSString *country = [_country objectAtIndex:self.displayedFlagIndex];

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on that `if` statement and checked the strings in the debugger?

Comment: @ArtemZaytsev why would that be any better? How would that help?

Comment: By the way, this has exactly **nothing** to do with Xcode. Like, at all.

Comment: basically I am trying to compare an element of NSArray and text entered into a textfield UI control

Answer (score 0):

Well, `isEqualToString:` works flawlessly. The only thing you need to mind is it does not do case insensitive comparison of string.

If you need that behaviour, please add following category on `NSString` and call it:

```
- (BOOL)isEqualIgnoreCaseToString:(NSString *)iString {
    return ([self caseInsensitiveCompare:iString] == NSOrderedSame);
}
```

Comment: Now it just takes if condition everytime